# How can I drag Excel formulas down without changing the row number, or right without changing the column number?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

*Removed the = from the formulas to allow me to post this...*

I have a sheet with 200 columns, and in all of them I need to achieve the following:

Col A

```
CLEAN('Sheet003'!C2)
CLEAN('Sheet003'!D2)
CLEAN('Sheet003'!E2)
CLEAN('Sheet003'!F2)
```

Dragging down changes the row number, but I need that to stay the same. I just need the column letter to change as above.

Col B

```
CLEAN('Sheet003'!C3)
CLEAN('Sheet003'!D3)
CLEAN('Sheet003'!E3)
CLEAN('Sheet003'!F3)
```

**If I drag to the right to apply the formula to the entire row (which is what I want), it changes the column, but I want that to stay the same.**

Does anyone have a solution to this that only involves dragging or some quick trick to achieve the drag across the entire row?

Comment: So, let me see if I understand, As you drag down you want to change the Column and when you drag across you want to change the row?

Comment: For Col A you can put the "$" in front of the number ie 'Sheet3'!C$2,  so when you drag down the number won't change but the column will if you drag right. Similar argument for putting a "$" in front of the letter...

Answer (score 1):

`OFFSET` can be used here. If the data of `Sheet003` starts at C2, input the formula below in cell A2 and you can drag down or right:

```
=CLEAN(OFFSET(Sheet003!$C$2,COLUMN()-1,ROW()-2))
```